# Must declare scalar variable in sql procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Please what is wrong with the procedure statement below

```
    DECLARE  @result int 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    set @result = (select COUNT(*) from populate)

    if (@result > 1)
    Begin
        insert into populate (brch, terminal_id) values(@branch, @atmid)
    end
```

---

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
     SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE insertion @id varchar(50), @brch varchar(50)
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

   AS
    BEGIN
   DECLARE  @result int 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    set @result  = (COUNT(*) from populate)

    if (@result > 1)
    Begin
        insert into populate (brch, terminal_id) values(@id, @brch)
    end
    END
    GO
```

Comment: please post your full stored procedure, including create statement

Comment: Do not get a `Count(*)` just to find out if there is more than one row! Do `SELECT Count(*) FROM (SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Populate)`. Also, you haven't posted enough of the procedure--if truly a stored procedure, where is the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have confused things by first posting a piece of code that gives the error `Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 11 Must declare the scalar variable "@branch".` and then later adding a complete procedure that gives the error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure insertion, Line 13 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.`

Please make sure that you post the real code you're using and the full error message too, otherwise people cannot help you.

Anyway, I ignored the code snippet and looked only at the procedure and as ABFORCE said, the problem is where you populate `@result` because your syntax is wrong. This procedure code parses without error in SQL Server 2008:

```
   CREATE PROCEDURE insertion @id varchar(50), @brch varchar(50)
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

   AS
    BEGIN
   DECLARE  @result int 
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    select @result  = COUNT(*) from populate

    if (@result > 1)
    Begin
        insert into populate (brch, terminal_id) values(@id, @brch)
    end
    END
    GO
```

You might want to review the documentation for [assigning values to variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175852%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) and the [`SET`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189484%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as it is said in the error message is that `@branch` and `@atmid` are not mentioned anywhere before their values are used.

You have declared `@result` and `set` it's value, so you need to do the same for `@branch` and `@atmid` as well, the system cannot divine the values for you.

Comment: IT gives the error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure populate, Line 17
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'.

Comment: We need way more information to give a more meaningful answer. Please edit the question, and give information about the schema of the data, about what the procedure does, about error messages etc. The SO community is great for solving problems, but still the problems must be correctly described.

Comment: No, you did not :) What is `populate`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select @result =COUNT(*) from populate
```